# Get HTML tag contents using php

Tags: php, regex, file-get-contents

Basically i get the contents from a `URL` using php `file_get_contents()`.

After getting the page source, i have to get the data from this part of the page source

```
<div class="span2 box-product" data-store="kimstore" data-product-id="cpnYKmW6D5" data-product-title="Nokia-900-Lumia">
<a href="/Nokia-900-Lumia/p-cpnYKmW6D5" title="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300">
    <img src="https://m-md.s3.amazonaws.com/storefront/kimstore/media/46/68/2d/99/68159647b67e5b1a2d124f9-120x90" width="120" height="90" title="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300" alt="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300" />
</a>
<p class="title">
    <a href="/Nokia-900-Lumia/p-cpnYKmW6D5" title="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300">
        Nokia 900 Lumia
    </a>
</p>
<p class="price">Php 14,300</p>
<p class="shop">
    <a href="/kimstore" title="kimstore">kimstore</a>
</p>
</div>
```

So, I have to get the data between `<div class="span2 box-product"` and its closing tags.

and then after that, I have to get 3 data from this:
 1. data-store
 2. data-product-title
 3. price

I have tried using `regex` but no luck that way. Any suggestions of what to do, technology to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are trying to do may be a) a copyright violation and b) the wrong approach. IANAL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleXML you can access the attributes, and the DOM, as a PHP object. Pass the result from file_get_contents to SimpleXML, like so :

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: i'll try this out but to tell you i am not getting xml url but html

Answer (score 0):

Use **DOM** extension (or **SimpleXML** if you parsing xhtml document).

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

SimpleXML may fail if your document is not **valid XML**.

Also you should learn about **xPath** to get fast access to any DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

With just the HTML code you have provided this solution will work:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="span2 box-product" data-store="kimstore" data-product-id="cpnYKmW6D5" data-product-title="Nokia-900-Lumia">
    <a href="/Nokia-900-Lumia/p-cpnYKmW6D5" title="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300">
        <img src="https://m-md.s3.amazonaws.com/storefront/kimstore/media/46/68/2d/99/68159647b67e5b1a2d124f9-120x90" width="120" height="90" title="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300" alt="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300" />
    </a>
    <p class="title">
        <a href="/Nokia-900-Lumia/p-cpnYKmW6D5" title="Nokia 900 Lumia Php 14,300">
            Nokia 900 Lumia
        </a>
    </p>
    <p class="price">Php 14,300</p>
    <p class="shop">
        <a href="/kimstore" title="kimstore">kimstore</a>
    </p>
</div>
HTML;

$sxe        = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
$attributes = $sxe->attributes();
$data_store = trim((string) $attributes['data-store']);
$title      = trim((string) $sxe->p[0]->a);
$price      = trim((string) $sxe->p[1]);

echo "{$data_store}\n{$title}\n{$price}\n";
```

Comment: but i have to get the data from the whole html.

Comment: This code snippet should be more than enough for you to understand how SimpleXML parsing works. Just load the whole HTML and navigate your way into the object until your reach the intended block.